# How to get listview row position clicked in in addtextchangedlistener

Tags: android, android-listview

I am writing a program which contain listview .
`listview` has one text boz and one `edittext`.
i want to know the position clicked inside the `addTextChangedListener`

Answer (score 1):

You can catch the position like below,

I use `onFocus` because if you use `addTextChangedListener`, it will assign the value for every typing.

Put the position to `edittext` tag then you can get it by `getTag()`.

```
edittext.setId(position); 
final int sPosition; 
edittext.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) { 
        sPosition = v.getId();
    }
}); 
edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() { 
    @Override 
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,int before, int count) {
        //
    } 

    @Override public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,int count, int after) {
        //
    } 

    @Override public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) { 
        // sPosition
    }
});
```